# Trouble booting off USB

Tags: boot-loader, live-usb, flash

I am having difficulty logging into my Linux Lite desktop, because it randomly decided to enforce a password. To fix this issue, I created a bootable USB. My first attempt was to access the BIOS and set USB as the highest priority. While, I can access the main menu, I can't move the cursor around or see any effect as I press enter.

2nd attempt was to access the command line and set the root to the USB. Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out which (...) To use for the root. Yes, I already tried (hd0,gpt1) and  (hd0,gpt2). I also unplugged it to see if it vanishes. That did not work, either.

How may I find the right command to finally boot from the flash stick?

Comment: Are you referring to a mouse cursor, or a text cursor that should be moveable with arrow keys? Some vendors have BIOS menus that support mouse, but not all of them. If you had a passwordless system accessible from the internet, it could have been hacked - and the hacker(s) could have set a password to try and prolong the time they can have the computer for themselves. Could you identify the make and model of the system or its motherboard?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have forgotten the motherboard's manufacturer.. Its model is B365M PRO-VDH. I am being sincere despite sounding sarcastic. All of the above.

Comment: [Does MSI sound familiar?](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B365M-PRO-VDH) Unfortunately [the manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/M7C39v1.0.pdf) has just one page of information on BIOS menus, and very little in the way of examples on selecting the boot media. But apparently pressing the F11 key when the system is executing a Power-On Self-Test should give you a boot menu, which should include an option to boot from USB media if one was plugged in when the power was switched on.